# Strtr в php как удалить слово а не заменить его пробелом?

Tags: php

```
$cmd = strtr($user_msg, [
            $text[0] => '',
            $text[1] => '',
            $text[2] => '',
            $text[3] => '']);
```

Нужно удалить $text[0], $text[1], $text[2] и $text[3], но они заменяются на пробел и записываются в БД с пробелами.

```
  $name = $text[1];
  $group = $text[2];
  $price = $text[3];
  $cmd = strtr($user_msg, [
        $text[0] => '',
        $text[1] => '',
        $text[2] => '',
        $text[3] => '']);
  $db->query("INSERT INTO products ('name', 'group', 'price', 'product_cmd') VALUES ('$name', '$group', $price, '$cmd')");
```

Comment: приведите конкретный пример кода, где заменяется на пробел

Comment: `$cmd = preg_replace('/'.join('|', $text).'/ui', '', $user_msg);`, где `$text` - массив удаляемых слов.

Comment: и чем не устраивает обычный `str_replace($user_msg, $text, '')` ?

Comment: Слова удаляются, но в переменной `$user_msg` они обрамлены пробелами, которые остаются после преобразований.

Comment: @teran тем что через него не заменить множество значений

Comment: @Let'ssayPie а без регулярок?

Comment: @teran привёл..

Comment: что значит не заменить множество? вполне себе принимает там и массив замен.  я в комменте потенциально рабочий пример кода привел, где `$text` ваш массив для поиска,  и заменяется на пустую строку.

Answer (score 0):

Немного дополню коммент от **teran** (не используя `strtr`):

```
trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', str_replace($text, '', $user_msg)));
```

Или так (используя `strtr`):

```
trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $cmd))
```

Оба варианта одинаково решают проблему "сквозных" пробелов.

[test](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/048e456fdf5d285d8dadd85b1af6cd5401d05824)

Comment: А без регулярок?

Comment: Вряд ли. Дело в том, что мы заранее не можем знать порядок слов в тексте. И может получиться так, что местами будет оставаться по несколько пробелов подряд. Их надо как-то санитайзить. Без регулярки только если  точно уверены, что нигде в тексте слова из набора замены не встретятся подряд.